# String to char array and to string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, char

How can I can convert char array to string array?

For example `"Text not text" → "Text not text" as char array → "Text" "not" "text"`

I understand how to `"Text not text" → "Text not text"`, but dont know how to

`"Text not text" as char array → "Text" "not" "text"`

Here is code example, but it does not work

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StringBuffer inString = new StringBuffer("text not text");
        int n = inString.toString().replaceAll("[^a-zA-ZА-Я а-я]", "")
                .split(" ").length;
        char[] chList = inString.toString().toCharArray();
        System.out.print("Text splited by chars - ");
        for (int i = 0; i < chList.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(chList[i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        String[] temp = new String[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < chList.length; j++) {
                if (chList[j] != ' ') {
                    temp[i] = new String(chList);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(temp[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you create a `String[n]`? Do you want a String for each char? or String as number of spaces +1?

Comment: thats possible when you will have to detect the words...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short sweet answer is [from anvarik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16147068/474189). However, if you need to show some working (maybe this is homework?), the following code will construct the list manually:

```
char[] chars = "text not text".toCharArray();

List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  char c = chars[i];

  builder.append(c);

  if (c == ' ' || i == chars.length - 1) {
    results.add(builder.toString().trim());
    builder = new StringBuilder();
  }
}

for (String s : results) {
  System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: true but possible when searched in dictionary , like word detector!!

Comment: But if space only beatwean words?

Answer (score 2):

So you have a char array as following am I right:

```
char[] chars = new char[] {'T', 'e', 'x', 't', ' ', 'n', 'o', 't', ' ', 't', 'e', 'x', 't'};
```

Then what you want to get is separate words `Text`, `not` and `text` ??

if so, then do the following:

```
String newString = new String(chars);
String[] strArray = newString.split(" ");
```

now `strArray` is your array.

Comment: Not correct. Then my text will be done from same splited text

Comment: @AntonArtemov Well... it *is* correct. Perhaps you've not explained all the rules of your assignment?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `String.split()` method.

Comment: This is certainly the simple answer if the question is "How do I split a sentence into words?"

Comment: Quetion is how to conver char array back to words!

Comment: Convert the char array to a String, and split the string.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you replace all the white spaces when you are converting "Text not text" with a $ symbol so the resulting string becomes 'T e x t$ n o t$ t e x t'

String ex= ex.replaceAll("\s","$");

and while converting it back you can replace the $ with white spaces again.

Other than this I can't seem to think any other way of how you can maintain the meanings of the words while splitting.

Comment: And if spaces onle beatwean words?